# ArchUnit layer test: how to exclude a specific class?

Tags: archunit

Is there the possibility to exclude a specific class from a layered test-condition in an ArchUnit-test?

I have packages A, B, C, D defined as follows:

```
<root>
+- A      <-- contains a factory class referring to B, C and D.
   +-B
   +-C
   +-D
```

Package A contains utility and base classes that are used and extended by classes in packages B, C, and D.
The rule should thus be that classes in A must NOT refer to anything in the extending packages EXCEPT that there is a factory class in A which refers to a bunch of leaf-classes in B, C, D. So that factory class needs to be excluded from that test.

```
ArchRule rule = Architectures.layeredArchitecture()
    .layer("A").definedBy("..a")
    .layer("B").definedBy("..a.b..")
    .layer("C").definedBy("..a.c..")
    .layer("D").definedBy("..a.d..")
    .whereLayer("A").mayOnlyBeAccessedByLayers("B", "C", "D", ... and others ...)
    .whereLayer("B").mayNotBeAccessedByAnyLayer() // except by "FactoryClass" in A
    .whereLayer("C").mayNotBeAccessedByAnyLayer() // except by "FactoryClass" in A
    .whereLayer("D").mayNotBeAccessedByAnyLayer() // except by "FactoryClass" in A
```

How can one phrase that "except by FactoryClass in A"-condition in ArchUnit?

Hope I could make myself clear...

Answer (score 1):

Layers of your architecture don't necessarily have to correspond 1:1 to packages.
You could use [`.layer("A").definedBy(DescribedPredicate<? super JavaClass>)`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.tngtech.archunit/archunit/0.16.0/com/tngtech/archunit/library/Architectures.LayeredArchitecture.LayerDefinition.html#definedBy(com.tngtech.archunit.base.DescribedPredicate)) to exclude `FactoryClass` from layer A.

Alternatively, you could probably keep it in layer A, but use [`LayeredArchitecture.ignoreDependency`](https://javadoc.io/static/com.tngtech.archunit/archunit/0.16.0/com/tngtech/archunit/library/Architectures.LayeredArchitecture.html#ignoreDependency(com.tngtech.archunit.base.DescribedPredicate,com.tngtech.archunit.base.DescribedPredicate)) to exclude its dependencies.